# Unable to get localhost IP using Docker

Tags: docker, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to use scrapy-splash, so I installed Docker Toolsbox on my Windows 7, after that I'm following those steps:

```
# Pull the image:
    docker pull scrapinghub/splash
# Start the container:
    docker run -p 8050:8050 -p 5023:5023 scrapinghub/splash
```

When I run the final line I got this message:

```
$ docker run -p 8050:8050 -p 5023:5023 scrapinghub/splash
2020-02-27 09:00:16+0000 [-] Log opened.
2020-02-27 09:00:17.520688 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':1917600420', '-screen
', '0', '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-splash'
2020-02-27 09:00:32.662453 [-] Splash version: 3.4.1
2020-02-27 09:00:43.522556 [-] Qt 5.13.1, PyQt 5.13.1, WebKit 602.1, Chromium 73
.0.3683.105, sip 4.19.19, Twisted 19.7.0, Lua 5.2
2020-02-27 09:00:43.523779 [-] Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) [GC
C 8.3.0]
2020-02-27 09:00:43.525499 [-] Open files limit: 1048576
2020-02-27 09:00:43.526626 [-] Can't bump open files limit
2020-02-27 09:00:44.041465 [-] proxy profiles support is enabled, proxy profiles
 path: /etc/splash/proxy-profiles
2020-02-27 09:00:44.043590 [-] memory cache: enabled, private mode: enabled, js
cross-domain access: disabled
2020-02-27 09:00:49.395125 [-] verbosity=1, slots=20, argument_cache_max_entries
=500, max-timeout=90.0
2020-02-27 09:00:49.397111 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled),
 Webkit: enabled, Chromium: enabled
2020-02-27 09:00:49.399925 [-] Site starting on 8050
2020-02-27 09:00:49.401080 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object
at 0x7f82942b71d0>
2020-02-27 09:00:49.404033 [-] Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8050
```

Why am I not able to get a localhost IP to use Splash ?

**EDIT:**

```
                       ##         .
              ## ## ##        ==
           ## ## ## ## ##    ===
       /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
       \______ o           __/
         \    \         __/
          \____\_______/

docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.102
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
```

I just copied the IP that docker shows from the first screen and pasted that in my browser with the listening port : 192.168.99.102:8050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2020-02-27 09:00:49.404033 [-] Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8050
```

0.0.0.0 means all interfaces.

Just navigate to http://localhost:8050

Comment: Adding to this: The argument "-p 8050:8050" in the docker run statement means that whatever is running inside the container on port 8050 is then mapped/forwarded to the host on port 8050. The syntax for this is "-p <host-port:container-port>. This means that you could run the same container by supplying the argument "-p 8051:8050", where the second container service would be available on port 8051 on your localhost.

Comment: In a "server listening on..." message inside a Docker container, 127.0.0.1 is "the loopback address for localhost" and means the container will be inaccessible from outside of Docker.  0.0.0.0 is "all interfaces".  They're very different.

Comment: @DavidMaze my bad. I will fix it:)